# Checking existence of HTML5 video src

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-video, http-status-code-404

Is there any way to check the existence of video file?

I tried ajax to check if video tag `src` URL exists or not (if it returns 404). But, due to the CORS, I'm not able to fetch required data.

Note to consider: Video is hosted on external domain which I don't have control to enable CORS.

Example video url: http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4
Need to check if exists before initiating play through JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus I just found the same question and was in the process of closing when you beat me to it :)

Comment: Ninja powers activate! ;-)

Comment: Ha ha.. thanks mates.. I'll check that answer :)